# How can I copy the state of an ifstream?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have a function that takes an ifstream, ifs, and uses it to fill this:
    std::vector< std::vector > matrix;
 (this is an assignment and I do not have any say in how to better implement this).
I would like to know length of the file I am reading before I begin filling "matrix"
This way, I will avoid constantly resizing.  However, I only have one ifstream object, ifs.  If I use a loop to find the length of the file, I will be at the end of the file and I am unsure how to 'refresh' an ifstream so that it is at the first line again.
Something else I was considering was creating a copy of ifs.  This way, I can loop through one ifstream, close it, and use the other one to fetch the data.
I feel like there would be an issue having two ifstreams open and pointed at the same file.

I do not know of a way to implement either idea.  Please assume that I can no longer access the original file name/path.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you'd want to do this copying thing.. reading from a stream is an I/O operation AFAIK and its a really bad idea to read the data two times.. you're better off inn performance doing mem resizing through vectors than you'll be reading from the stream again

Comment: How is the matrix encoded in the file? How do you know its size?

Comment: The matrix will have a row for each line and a column for each character in a line; it can become rather large.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to copy streams.
To jump to the beginning, just use [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/):

```
ifs.seekg(0);
```

If you reached the end of the stream before seeking, another problem is that the stream remembers the file end internally and seekg doesn't reset this. For this to work, use

```
ifs.clear();
```

before seeking.

Comment: weren't streams I/O bound...? I mean its better to re-size a vector than to reread an entire stream..? until of-course the the re-sizing is almost infinite times.. which might even be faster than reading a never ending stream..

Comment: In this case, it's probably better, yes. In general case, files won't fit into RAM.

Comment: Is reading the entire stream necessary if your only goal is to find the number of lines?

Comment: @user3753669 Finding the number of lines means you need to find and count line breaks, which could be anywhere in the file. Yes, it's necessary to read the file for that.

Comment: @deviantfan
This results in the file only being displayed once when I expected it to appear on the console twice. 

string x; 
while (std::getline(ifs, x)) { cout << x << endl; } 
ifs.seekg(0); 
while (std::getline(ifs, x)) { cout << x << endl; }

Comment: @deviantfan "Error 1 error C2039: 'reset' : is not a member of 'std::basic_ifstream<char,std::char_traits<char>>'"
I looked at a few methods with your idea in mind and found ifs.clear() produces the result as ifs.reset() in your example.
Thank you!

Comment: @user3753669 Whoops, right, it's clear. edit: Thanks for the upvote, 7777 rep is funny :D